# How to start a tail on tty1 on boot without logging in?

Tags: linux, boot

I want my (embedded) system to start a certain `tail example.log` on `tty1` on boot. I tried just adding

```
tail -f /home/foo/example.log &
```

to `rc.local`, and this does start the `tail`, but after some characters, nothing is output to `tty1` anymore (the process still runs though).

How can I start a log on `tty1`, on boot, without logging in or typing anything?

The device is running "Debian 7 (wheezy)", kernel 3.2.0

Comment: Can you tell if the system uses `systemd` (`getty@tty1.service`)? or something else (`/etc/init/tty1.conf` maybe)?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski how do I do that?  `systemd` runs, so I guess yes.

Comment: Then follow [this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/211544/108618).